# Are these statements needed to find the area of a triangle?

Tags: triangles, area

[image]

Given a figure above (I'm sorry if the figure is not too clear). Consider the statements below.

1. Area of $BDE$ is $=32\, \mathrm{cm}^2$.
2. Area of $DEF$ is $=\frac{32}{3} \, \mathrm{cm}^2$.

Which statement is needed to find the area of $ABC$? (We can choose one of them or both of them or none of them).

I thought I should use similarity properties but I don't know what to do.

Comment: Triangle $ABC$ is similar to triangle $BDE$, but we cannot find the area of $ABC$ unless we know one of the sides.

Comment: Are the points $D$ and $E$ the midpoints of the sides they're on?

Comment: Is the question asking if "one of them, both of them or none of them" are sufficient to find the area of ABC? If so, the answer should be None. The information is not sufficient.

Comment: @RANGGAJAYA CIPTAWAN, the given information is helpful only when it is given that $DE||AC$ or $\displaystyle\frac{BD}{DA}=\frac{BE}{EC}$.

Comment: @Bernard there's no information about it

Comment: @SarGe it's given that $DE||AC$, but we don't know whether $\frac{BD}{DA}=\frac{BE}{EC}$.